# Jack или Android Studio 3.0 Beta

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

Какой подход сейчас лучше использовать для работы с Java 8 в Android Studio? Использовать стабильную версию Android Studio вместе с Jack, или же использовать  Android Studio 3.0 Beta?

Как я понимаю, Google поощряет отказываться от Jack:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/java-8-language-features-support-update.html

но нет ли подводных камней в использовании Beta-версии Android Studio 3.0?

Comment: Jack мертв.....

Comment: Если проект новый, то, по моему мнению, его лучше сразу начинать на Kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jack признан нежизнеспособным начиная с Gradle Android Plugin 2.4, поэтому единственный способ использовать Java 8 при условии minSdk < 26 - desugar.
Данный механизм поддерживает не все фичи Java 8 на старых версиях андроида (см. [список](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features))

Если нет жесткого ограничения (например вы разрабатываете библиотеку для приложений на Java) - можно использовать Kotlin (даже со студией 2.3)

На текущий момент Android Studio 3.0-beta7 стабильна и используется многими (как с Java, так и с Kotlin)